# laravel ajax call post/put give 500/404 internal server error but works in local server

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I really don't understand this:

```
   jQuery('.myCheckbox').click(function() {

        if($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "comparecustom",
                data:  {
                    'product_id':  prdidtable,
                    'term_id':     checkboxData,
                    'sort_list_id': sort_list_id
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                complete : function(){  // this will be called even if our request fail, success etc
                }

            });

            $('.mybestall_'+checkboxData).prop('checked',false);

        }
        else if($(this).not(':checked')) 
        {
            $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'comparecustom',
                data:  {
                    'product_id':  prdidtable,
                    'term_id':     checkboxData,
                    'delete_data': delete_data
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                complete : function(){  // this will be called even if our request fail, success etc
                }

            });
        } 

    });
```

My Route:

```
Route::post('comparecustom', array('before' => 'csrf', 'uses' => 'compares@comparecustom'));
```

My Contrlller:

```
if(Request::AJAX())
        {

}
```

In works fine in Localhost, but when I transfer to live server returns POST/PUT 500/404 error respectively. I have tried many different ways still cant find a solution.

it works perfectly in localhost, why doesn't it work in live server?

Please help? csrf_token?

Could it be csrf_token which I need to pass along with Ajax call: 
I tried that too no luck

Comment: try again by clearing in local `php artisan cache:clear` & `php artisan view:clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! I have solved it by having a "/" in my route. "/" was added in the beginning:

Route::post('/products/(:any)/comparecustomdata', array('uses' => 'compares@comparecustomdata'));

all other route do not have "/". that was confused me.

so problem solved.

thank you everyone for your help